# Very simple insert function, no data get's stored and no errors received

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to add a button that generates dummy data into a table with 1 click

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

include("classes/db.class.php");

$currentTime = time();
$totalUsers = '20000';
$usersUS1 = '5000';
$usersUS2 = '5263';
$usersFR1 = '8000';
$usersHK1 = '7425';
$usersUK1 = '0';

  if(!empty($_POST))
  {
    $currentTime = time();
    $db = new db();
    $sql = "INSERT into connections (users, us1, us2, fr1, hk1, time, uk1) VALUES
            ('".$db->conn->real_escape_string($totalUsers) ."' ,
            '". $db->conn->real_escape_string($usersUS1) ."' ,
            '". $db->conn->real_escape_string($usersUS2) ."' ,
            '". $db->conn->real_escape_string($usersFR1) ."' ,
            '". $db->conn->real_escape_string($usersHK1) ."',
            '". $db->conn->real_escape_string($currentTime) ."',
            '". $db->conn->real_escape_string($usersUK1) ."')";
    $result = $db->conn->query($sql);
    return $result;
  }
?>
```

However everytime I press the button, I receive 0 errors and nothing gets stored in the DB.

The php code and html are on the same page.

Does anyone know what's causing the problem?

**EDIT**:

*DB class:*

```
<?php
    class db
    {
        private $m_sHost = "localhost";
        private $m_sUserlogin = "root";
        private $m_sPassword = "root";
        private $m_sDatabase = "radius";

        public $conn;

        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->conn = new mysqli($this->m_sHost, $this->m_sUserlogin, $this->m_sPassword, $this->m_sDatabase);
        }
    }
?>
```

*and the form I use to post:*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>screen wall</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
    <!--<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>-->
    <script src="scripts/d3-3.5.2/d3.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <p> Current Timestamp:<?php echo time(); ?> </p>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" required="required" name="titel" value="test field :)">
    <button type="submit" id="generateBtn">Add Data</button>
</form>
</body>
```

Again, HTML and PHP are on the same page.

Comment: Are you sure you're sending a POST request to the page?

Comment: Can you also post your db class?

Comment: You should really used prepared statements in this case to mitigate SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @CPUTerminator I know but this is just for myself, we have to work with data from the last 6 hours, so this is just a script that puts dummy content in the db. The script wont actually be online.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first: You should not be using the `real_escape_string` since the input is not from the user whereas it is hard coded in the code itself.

Secondly an alternative way to rectify the issue is you can use

```
if (!mysqli_query($db->conn,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";
```

instead of

```
$result = $db->conn->query($sql);
```

Hope this helps.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I changed the code to http://puu.sh/jnu5G/d933a6416d.png but now I get 'Notice: Undefined property: mysqli::$5000 in D:\Developpement\MAMP\htdocs\VPN\newdata.php on line 25'

Comment: @PrashantTapase It's $totalUsers, where I start defining the variables

Comment: It should not be `$db->conn->$totalUsers` instead you should only write `$totalUsers` because it is local variables not inside the db class.